# How to sort blank arrays to the top so I can delete them

Tags: c, arrays

```
int id_swap()
{
    char tempstring[15];

    strcpy(tempstring, id[index+1]);
    strcpy(id[index+1], id[index]);
    strcpy(id[index], tempstring);
}

int delete_student()
{
    int found=0;
    char id_to_find[10];

    printf("Please enter the student ID to delete\n\n");
    scanf("%s", & id_to_find);
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    for(index=0;index<height_of_array+1;index++)
    {
        if(strcmpi(id_to_find, id[index]) == 0)
        {
            found=1;
            id_swap();
            system("cls");
            printf("Student deleted");
            height_of_array = height_of_array--;
        }
```

Okay so that's part of my code. A quick example of what happens

I sort the students that are already in the program so it comes up like this for e.g

```
Student#1 Chris ID: 1831
Student#2 etc
student#3 etc
student#4 Brian ID: 4432
student#5 etc
student#6 etc
```

But when I try to delete say Brian for example, it deletes it but then it looks like this

```
student#1 ID:
Student#2 Chris ID:1831
Student#3 etc
```

Is there any way to move that blank array to the last position so I can then decrement my "Height_of_array" so that the number of storable students goes down by 1 to reflect the deletion

Comment: Please, do yourself and us a favor and format your code in a readable manner.

Comment: Where's height_of_array defined? Also your code looks like suddenly cut...

Comment: Please add the homework tag if appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code: that jump at me:

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

Never do that. Only flush output streams.

```
height_of_array = height_of_array--;
```

Is undefined behavior, you meant:

```
height_of_array--;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried it but it then removed 3 of the other arrays and not just the one I was trying to remove :/

Comment: It's probably because you don't decrement `index` when you remove elements.